# For 1-D `X`, what is the difference between `X[n]` and `X[..., n]`?

Tags: python, numpy, ellipsis

When using an `ellipsis` (`...`) to index an 1-D `ndarray`, I would expect  the expressions `X[0]` and `X[..., 0]` to be semantically identical.  However, their string representations differ:

```
In [522]: X = arange(5) 

In [523]: repr(X[0])                         
Out[523]: '0'

In [524]: repr(X[..., 0])
Out[524]: 'array(0)'
```

I can't find any other differences, and indeed, they are equal according to `array_equal`:

```
In [526]: array_equal(X[0], X[..., 0])
Out[526]: True
```

If they are equal according to `array_equal`, why do they have different string representations?

Comment: As @CharlieHaley says, the different string representations are because one of these is giving you a scalar, and the other a 0-dimensional NumPy array. I have no idea why the `...` leads to a 0-d array, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`X[0]` returns a `numpy.int64` object.
When you say `X[0]`, you are telling python to give you the object at index 0 in array `X`.

`X[...,0]` returns a 0 dimensional numpy array.
When you say `X[...,0]`, you are telling python to give you the items at index 0 along the last axis of array `X`.

Comment: Hmm. That's not really what the `...` means. In `X[..., 0]`, you're specifying that you're only interested in index `0` for the *last* axis of `X`, but for all preceding axes you're taking the full range of indices. If you try this on a 2d array, you'll see that `X[..., 0]` gives you a 1d result.

Comment: Yes, I phrased that incorrectly. You hit the nail on the head.